# Smart Value for user who performed transition in Jira

Tags: jira

Having looked through the [Jira smart values documentation for issues](https://support.atlassian.com/cloud-automation/docs/jira-smart-values-issues/) I can see no obvious way of printing out which user has performed a transition.

The use case for this is to be able to send a notification like:

> **Jane Doe** transitioned **Awesome Issue** to *Done*

Is it possible to display which user has transitioned an issue??

Answer (score 1):

Jira's smart value for this is `[~accountid:{{initiator.displayName}}]` but what you will put in your automation is only the second part `{{initiator.displayName}}`.

If you are doing an edit on a user picker field it may appear as if the field only allows existing users from your tenant. However once you complete the smart value it will show a context that allows you to select your value.
[image]

I found this answer thanks to a medium.com post by Jacob Harrison
[All (useful) Jira Issue Smart Values, Macros, Issue Details, ID Keys](https://medium.com/@jacobthomasharrison/all-available-jira-issue-smart-values-macros-issue-details-id-keys-608ef5eadd31)

Comment: This is only for the Jira Cloud, JSM Server or JSM Data Center editions may have different values for this.

Comment: Thanks @Alex! This pointed me in the right direction - what I needed for my example was `{{initiator.displayName}}`. If you update your answer to account for that I'll set it as accepted :)

Comment: I've updated the details and the screenshot!